# Rust deadlock with shared struct: Arc + channel + atomic

Tags: rust, concurrency, parallel-processing, deadlock

I'm new to Rust and was trying to generate plenty of JSON data on the fly for a project, but I'm having deadlocks.

I've tried removing the serialization (json_serde) and sending the HashMaps in the channel instead but I still get deadlocks on my computer. If I however comment the send(generator.next()) line and send a string myself, code works flawlessly, thus the deadlock is caused by my DatasetGenerator, but I don't understand why.

Code summary:

- Have a DatasetGenerator object that can generate sequences of "events" and serialize them to JSON.
- generator.next() works like an "iterator" - It increments an internal atomic counter in the generator and then generates the i-th item in the sequence + serializes the JSON.
- Have a generator threadpool generate these JSONs at high throughput (very large payloads each)
- Send these JSONs through a channel to other thread (which will send them through network but irrelevant for this question)

Depending if I comment `tx_ref.send(generator_ref.next())` or  `tx_ref.send(some_new_string)` below my code deadlocks or succeeds:

src/main.rs:

```rust
extern crate threads_pool;

use threads_pool::*;

mod generator;

use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    // N will be an argument, and a very high number. For tests use this:
    const N: i64 = 12;  // Increase this if you're not getting the deadlock yet, or run cargo run again until it happens.
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    let tx_producer = tx.clone();
    let producer_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);
        let generator = Arc::new(generator::data_generator::DatasetGenerator::new(3000));
        for i in 0..N {
            println!("Generating #{}", i);
            let tx_ref = tx_producer.clone();
            let generator_ref = generator.clone();
            pool.execute(move || {
                ////////// v !!!DEADLOCK HERE!!! v ////////// 
                tx_ref.send(generator_ref.next()).expect("tx failed.");              // This locks!
                //tx_ref.send(format!(" {}            ", i)).expect("tx failed.");   // This works!
                ////////// ^ !!!DEADLOCK HERE!!! ^ ////////// 
            })
            .unwrap();
        }

        println!("Generator done!");
    });

    println!("-» Consumer consuming!");
    for j in 0..N {
        let s = rx.recv().expect("rx failed");
        println!("-» Consumed #{}:   {} ...     ", j, &s[..10]);
    }
    println!("Consumer done!!");

    producer_thread.join().unwrap();
    println!("Success. Exit!");
}
```

This is my DatasetGenerator which seems to be causing all the trouble (as not using serde but outputting the HashMaps still gives deadlocks). src/generator/dataset_generator.rs:

```rust
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::atomic;

pub struct DatasetGenerator {
    num_features: usize,
    pub counter: atomic::AtomicI64,
    feature_names: Vec<String>,
}

type Datapoint = HashMap<String, Value>;
type Out = String;

impl DatasetGenerator {
    pub fn new(num_features: usize) -> DatasetGenerator {
        let mut feature_names = Vec::new();

        for i in 0..num_features {
            feature_names.push(format!("f_{}", i));
        }

        DatasetGenerator {
            num_features,
            counter: atomic::AtomicI64::new(0),
            feature_names,
        }
    }

    /// Generates the next item in the sequence (iterator-like).
    pub fn next(&self) -> Out {
        let value = self.counter.fetch_add(1, atomic::Ordering::SeqCst);
        self.gen(value)
    }

    /// Generates the ith item in the sequence. DEADLOCKS!!! ///////////////////////////
    pub fn gen(&self, ith: i64) -> Out {
        let mut data = Datapoint::with_capacity(self.num_features);

        for f in 0..self.num_features {
            let name = self.feature_names.get(f).unwrap();
            data.insert(name.to_string(), Value::from(ith));
        }

        serde_json::json!(data).to_string()  // Tried without serialization and still deadlocks!
    }
}
```

Commit with deadlock code is here if you want to try out yourself with `cargo run`: https://github.com/AlbertoEAF/learn-rust/tree/dc5fa867e5a70b605553ef65796fdc9dd42d38a0/rest-injector

Deadlock on Windows with Rust 1.60.0:
[image: Deadlock on Windows with Rust 1.60.0]

Thank you for the help! it's greatly appreciated :)

---

## Update

I've followed the suggestions from @kmdreko's answer below, and apparently the problem is in the generator: not all the items are generated. Even though `pool.execute()` is called N times, only a random number of closures c < N are executed even if I place `pool.close()` before leaving the `producer_thread`. **Why does that happen / How can it be fixed?**

**Fix:** Turns out this lockup is caused by the threads_pool library (0.2.6).  I switched the thread pool to rayon's and it worked smoothly at the first try.

Comment: You don't seem to have any locks with which a deadlock can even occur; can you clarify the behavior you're seeing? Do you mean your consumer loop does not finish?

Comment: Yes, that's the behaviour, it just stops randomly on an iteration forever. I thought I was causing a deadlock as it didn't abort nor finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should change: an `mpsc::Receiver` will return an error on `.recv()` if it cannot possibly yield a result by realizing that all the associated `mpsc::Sender`s have dropped, which is a good indicator that all the work is done. Your `tx_ref`s and even `tx_producer` will be dropped when their respective tasks/threads complete, however you still have `tx` in scope that can *theoretically* give a value. This is what gives you the apparent deadlock. You should simply remove `tx_producer` and use `tx` directly so it is moved into the producer thread and dropped accordingly.

Now, you'll see either all `N` tasks complete, or you'll get an error indicating that some tasks did not complete. The reason not all tasks are completing is because you're creating the thread pool, spawning all the tasks, and then immediately destroying it. The [`threads_pool`](https://crates.io/crates/threads_pool) documentation says that the threads will finish their current job when the pool is destroyed, but you want to wait until *all* jobs have completed. For that you need to call the `.close()` method provided by the [`PoolManager`](https://docs.rs/threads_pool/0.2.6/threads_pool/trait.PoolManager.html) trait before the end of the closure.

The reason you saw inconsistent behavior, but was benefited by returning a string directly is because the jobs required less work and the threads could get away with completing all them before they saw their signal to exit. Your `generator_ref.next()` requires much more computation so its not surprising they'd only process 4-plus-a-bit jobs before they see they've been told to exit.

Comment: Thanks kmdreko, that makes a lot of sense! What a great explanation! Thank you :)

Comment: I just tried removing tx_producer, and I get the RecvError now. I added `pool.close()` before `println!("Generator done!");` but didn't work either, the pool doesn't execute all the closures even the N execute calls are done @kmdreko

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with the `threads_pool` crate so maybe `.close()` doesn't do what I'd expect, I'm just going off of the documentation.

Comment: Ok, I just switched to rayon's ThreadPool and it worked right away.